# Unknown Class when using Volley Simple Request

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm following [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html)

And this is the code I have but for some reason the last line queue.add(stringRequest); is erroring with Unknown Class.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


final TextView mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    queue.add(stringRequest)
}

RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url = "http://www.google.com";

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        mTextView.setText("Response is: " + response.substring(0, 500));
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        mTextView.setText("That didnt work!");
    }
});
}
```

Do you know why it would be erroring?

Below is the error

```
Process: za.co.stillie.networktest, PID: 11113
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{za.co.stillie.networktest/za.co.stillie.networktest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1884)
            at za.co.stillie.networktest.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:25)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The above error is what I get when I try running my application with that error still in the code

NOTE: I moved queue.add(stringRequest) to the onCreate method

Comment: please post the whole stack trace of the error.

Comment: Iv followed the code on the site linked above and for some reason add in queue.add cannot be resolved? Thats all i can really give you

Comment: you say you get an error "Unknown Class". It is unclear what you mean by this. Usually, when you get an error, its accompanied by a complete stack trace of the error which typically tells you exactly where the error emanated from, and all the steps along the way which led to it. This information is crucial to solving this (or any) error.

Comment: Please see modifications above @GilMoshayof

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `queue.add(stringRequest)` is inside MainActivity but not in any of the function.

Just put `queue.add(stringRequest)` inside the onCreate or any other function that will be called.

`Unknown Class` is because Java treat 'queue.add(stringRequest)' as a variable, it doesn't know which class it belongs.
You don't have the stack trace of the error because Java won't let you run this code.

The website you gave didn't list all the code, but just a brief.

I don't have enough reputation for comment...
So do you declare this activity in mannifest, as well as the Network permission?

I guess you should use `findViewById` after setContentView.

```
final TextView mTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: Yes 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

and the Activity is there

Comment: Thanks...you save me..I was in interview when I got ERROR...@Kay Wu

Answer (score 2):

> you can't initiate textview or any view ..before setting
>   contentview...

ok ..i've found the error...you first add the stringrequest to queue and then initiate it...i've update the answer ..check it.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url = "http://www.google.com";

//dont mean to do that...
//final TextView mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
TextView mTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    mTextView.setText("Response is: " + response.substring(0, 500));
}
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    mTextView.setText("That didnt work!");
}
});

queue.add(stringRequest);
}


}
```

Comment: i tried that but i am still getting that java.lang.NullPointerException error?

Comment: can u tell me...at which line you'r getting NPE..and what was the code at that line?

Comment: by process of elimination it is RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this); is where it is crashing

Comment: i've found the error...you first add the stringrequest to queue and then initiate it...i've update the answer ..check it.